# Comparing two Strings using .equals() returns False, but their byte arrays are equal

Tags: java, string, byte, equals

I'm having some troubles when trying to send an image from a client to a server, because original image is different to the recieved one. In order to find the problem, i'm reading line by line of both image looking for the difference. When I compare the Strings line by line, for some lines using String#equals (e.g. lineo.equals(lined)) result is false, but as they seemed to be the same when I print them in the console, I also compare their byte arrays. Surprisingly, using Array.equals(lineo.getBytes(), lined.getBytes()) result is true. Both client and server are in the same computer.

Please help me to understand

1. Where can I find the difference between both Strings
2. Why both methods to compare, returns different results

   ```
   private void compareImages() throws IOException {
       File dest = new File("C:\\TempFiles\\" + fileName);
       File orig = new File("C:\\Users\\Andres\\Desktop\\B&N\\" + fileName);

       BufferedReader bro = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(orig));
       BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dest));

       String lineo = bro.readLine();
       String lined = brd.readLine();
       System.out.println("Ready to read");
       while (lineo!= null && lined!= null) {
           if(!lined.equals(lineo))
           {
               System.out.println("lineo");
               System.out.println(lineo);
               System.out.println("lined");
               System.out.println(lined);
               System.out.println("arrayo");
               System.out.println(printArray(lineo.getBytes()));
               System.out.println("arrayd");
               System.out.println(printArray(lined.getBytes()));
               System.out.println("Are: " + Arrays.equals(lined.getBytes(),     lineo.getBytes()));
               break;
           }
           lineo = bro.readLine();
           lined = brd.readLine();
       }
       bro.close();
       brd.close();
   }

   public String strArray(byte[] array){
       String toRet = "";
       for (byte b : array) {
           toRet += b;
       }
       return toRet;
   }
   ```

   The result of the console was:

> lineo
>
> ÿÄ µ }!AQa"q2?‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚
>
> lined
>
> ÿÄ µ }!AQa"q2?‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚
>
> arrayo
>
> 11-1-600-751602133243554400112512304175183349656198197734113205063-111-9583566-79-632182-47-16365198114-1269
>
> arrayd
>
> 11-1-600-751602133243554400112512304175183349656198197734113205063-111-9583566-79-632182-47-16365198114-1269
>
> Are: true

Please, have in mind that I could not copy some characters from the output.

Regards,

Andrés

Comment: What's the input, what's the output?

Comment: My guess is you're trying to read and compare images as strings and not accounting for possible encoding differences between client and server. Images are binary data, reading them as strings is pointless.

Comment: You can try compare strings charecter-by-character and find which of them different.

Comment: FYI you can use slash ("`/`") for the dir separator and Java will convert it behind the scene. e.g. `"C:/TempFiles/" + fileName` might be easier to read

Comment: Strings don't have byte arrays. `String.getBytes()` *converts* the string to a byte array using the default platform encoding, which means converting from UTF-16 to who knows what, and there are many things that could go wrong there, as well as many that could go wrong when reading binary image data as strings with a BufferedReader.

Comment: If you really want to find out why the strings are different, look at the characters in the strings, or step into the `equals` method in a debugger.

Comment: Can you display the arrays by doing `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(...))`?

Comment: So to conclude, although both client and server are in the same computer I cannot do this using Strings to read binary files. Also, the String#equal  issue is because i'm not reading properly the binary file and the conversion to byte array doesn't works for me in this case. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @an3sarmiento The `String#equals()` vs `Arrays.equals()` issue was caused by the fact that some encodings don't support all Unicode characters, so two different characters might get encoded as the same byte sequences (e.g. representing `?`), as in the example in Paul's answer. If you used `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, the byte arrays would be different whenever the strings are different.

Comment: @Cinnam, so its better to encode, decode using a standard that support all Unicode characters, just in case I cannot avoid

Comment: @an3sarmiento I think it's a good idea to always use a Unicode-capable encoding if you have the choice, or at least always specify what encoding you are using, instead of leaving it to platform default.

Comment: I will have it in mind, thanks @Cinnam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unequal strings do not have to produce different arrays when you do `getBytes()`.

The result depends on the platform's default charset, but when I run the following code

```
String str1 = "?";
byte[] arr1 = str1.getBytes();
String str2 = "\u0080";
byte[] arr2 = str2.getBytes();
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2));
```

the output I see is

```
false
true
```

I don't know exactly what is going on here, but it looks like certain control characters get treated as `'?'`.

The correct way to understand why strings are different is to compare the character arrays returned by `toCharArray()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Paul, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: A question mark is the replacement character in some character sets for characters that cannot be represented. You'll get that for US-ASCII or Cp1252, for instance. If your charset is UTF-8, you'll get 0xc2 0x80. For ISO-8859-1 you'll actually just get 0x80. The safest thing to do is assume the default encoding is EBCDIC, and act accordingly.

Comment: The `getBytes()` method has [unspecified behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) when it encounters characters it cannot encode. The `Charset.defaultCharset()` method returns the JVM's default encoding, but I'm not sure if that's the same as the one used by `getBytes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing images using strings might not be the best way to about it. 
Compare their byte (Use ByteArrayInputStream).

The strings' return character could be different or there might be some encoding differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are funny things. Strings are immutable. If you create two strings with the same value they both point to the same reference in memory. This is called interning. If you update one of those strings we get a new value in memory and the pointer of your variable points to the new value.

When you create your two strings you're assigning different values to them, it doesn't care if one is encoded and the other isn't, it doesn't actually know the difference at this point. You therefore have two string variables pointing to different values. When you do a .equals() you're checking the equivalency of the two string objects (do they point to the same thing; no they do not; therefore false).

[Here's a good article from Microsoft that explains it better than I can.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Darren very, interesting information about Strings!